# Java class finder Tool

Tags: java, classpath

Anyone who uses Java regularly knows the amount of trouble multiple jars in classpath can give us. I am looking for a tool which will help me -

1. Search for class files inside jars in **Classpath**
2. Search for class files inside jars in a **specific location**
3. Maybe too much to ask for but show me if the same class is present in multiple jars.

Also needless to say it should be fast. Most of the tools i have evaluated are very slow and not upto the mark.

Any tools for the above purpose greatly appreciated.

---

Currently i use WinRar achieve search(which BTW is really fast) to search for class files inside jars in a specific location. But there is no way to utilize that to search in Classpath.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an IDE, such as Eclipse? And then search for a type?

Comment: IDE can be used but unfortunately not every time (e.g. code deployed in weblogic server) and also i use maven2 for dependency management in a large code base with multiple projects. Bottom line - I am looking for more functionality than what the IDE type search can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eclipse, then IBM's [classfinder](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/jarclassfinder) may be useful. You can perform a (fuzzy) search for a class in a (set of) directories, and get all jar that contains such a class.

Not sure about the classpath option, however.

regards,
Guillaume

Comment: Sounds interesting. Currently investigating.

Comment: the classlocator plugin perform similar operation (http://classlocator.sourceforge.net/). . The main differnce is that the index is build once in the classlocator, whereas the directories where searched each time with IBM classfinder.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Bash this script may be helpful:

```
find . -name *.jar -exec bash -c "echo {} && jar tvf {} | grep MyClass" \;
```

Comment: Looks really interesting but unfortunately i use windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jarbrowser](http://jarbrowser.sourceforge.net/) for this

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, and they're on your classpath, you can CapitalCaseControlSpace what you want.

For example, if I want to get a new ApacheFanUtilityMethodizerFunctor (which everyone needs, of course) I simply type AFUMF and then Ctrl+Space and it populates it for me. Since it's already on my classpath, I don't need to hunt for it, because it's there.

Now, if it wasn't on my classpath, and I had to find what jar it was in for purposes of including it, then back to WinRAR (or for me, Google typically) I go.

Comment: Unfortunately I have Maven2 and a large code base(multiple app servers) wherein each project may have different dependencies, sometimes even different versions(long story). Hence I am looking for something more powerful than eclipse type search.

Comment: Eclipse was designed to be able to handle those, and correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe Maven has a plugin for eclipse which can pull the dependencies down so you can work with them.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution for managing java jars files and java classpath is really simple. Firstly I create folder inside e.g.:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\libraries\
```

Here I put all my *.jar files which i need to use.
Then I modify the:

```
PATH(modyfy also CLASSPATH or JAVA_HOME)
```

system variable and add this path shown above.

Problem occurs when one class is in two diffrent jars but I managed my jar to avoid this problem.

Now when java is running jvm can find my classes and ClassNoFoundException isn't thrown.

Answer (score 0):

A late response, but in case anyone searching has a similar problem, I wrote a simple tool a few years back that I use all the time for this sort of problem.

It's free to use and open source.  If you find it useful, let me know, :-)

https://github.com/eurozulu/Findclass