# Tools for finding all dependencies in Java jars

Tags: java, classloader

Are there any tools that can be given a classpath or folder, and will search through all the .jar files looking for references to a particular class?

It would have saved me a day of searching in order to resolve [this kind of problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043391/jboss-4-2-startup-throws-noclassdeffounderror).

In my case I had to find out where a rogue reference to a class was coming from, as it was stopping JBoss from starting correctly due to a `NoClassDefFoundError`. I suppose I am looking for this:

```
java -jar magicbullet.jar /path/to/search com.myproject.DodgyClass
Searching...
com.problematic.Otherclass in /path/to/search/dodgy.jar implements com.myproject.DodgyClass
```

Or similar. If not, I'll write one.

Comment: See [Java class finder Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577543/java-class-finder-tool)

Comment: The more I read this, the less I understand. What is your question? Do you only want to find in what jar a certain class is located, or do you want to know who it is that is referencing a certain class?

Comment: In my case I wanted to find which class in which jar was referencing a specific other class. I spent ages trying to find where a NoClassDefError was coming from, in the end discovering that one of the classes in one of our jars implemented an interface that wasn't in the classpath. JBoss's error message was less than helpful. A tool like the one I'm looking for could find that very quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Tattletale - http://www.jboss.org/tattletale. It helps you create an index which is very handy to search for classes etc.

Comment: Looks like a cool tool, but couldn't see that it answered the question "what classes are referencing class X"

Comment: Tattletale absolutely gives you the answer to "what classes are referencing class X" as well as "what classes X depends on". It also gives dependencies between jar files. Further it tells you about transitive dependencies and circular dependencies. The report that I find most useful is 'Class Location' which helps solve classpath problems if a class is getting loaded from a wrong jar version.

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux (or Cygwin on Windows) you may use script from https://gist.github.com/980697.

Usage: `findclass.sh <directory> <className>`

Example: `findclass.sh . ClassName` (means "search for class named ClassName inside all jars/wars/ears/sars located within current directory and all its subdirectories")

Comment: That won't tell if a class is referencing another class or not.

Comment: But it will tell where the missing class is located. Thus, NoClassDefFoundError could be fixed just by adding additional jar to the runtime classpath (or by replacing wrong jar with correct one).

Answer (score 0):

Google for "JarAnalyzer" a helpfull tool doing more exactly what you want (and a bit more ;D )